# python: de-serializing objects

Tags: object, deserialization

We have classes of this form `classA version1, classA version2, classA version3` .. etc. This is same class that has been modified. Each "modification" creates a new version of a class.  Each object has a version attribute which refers to the version of the class from which it was derived. eg `ObjectA.version =1` # means it was derived from `ClassA version1`

Here is my problem. During object de-serializing, i would like to use the specific version of the class that was used to used to make the object. For example, if i am de-serializing object `ObjectA` with `version=3` then `ClassA version 3` should be used. Source code for all the different variations of the classes is stored.

This looks getting the object first the get the class. Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Do the classes have the same data members? If not, is each version a superset of the last?

Comment: @Marcin, the classes may not have the same data members

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Custom serialisation/deserialisation - you can put version information and class information first.
2. Create a "union class" which has all of the members of all of the class versions, then use that to create an instance of the appropriate class.
3. Refactor to a common base class, and have each "version" inherit from that class.

I would recommend option 3, because then your versions can co-exist cleanly.